# Nav Bar How do I change the text color?

Tags: css

I've been reading about CSS Specificity and have tried several options including

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

in the bootstrap.css file but with no luck. What am i missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`.navbar-default .navbar-brand` means that style will be applied to `.navbar-brand` only when placed under `.navbar-default`. There is no such parent in your case.

You could change it to `.navbar .navbar-brand` or add `.navbar-default` to `nav` tag above

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework like bootstrap, then it can be difficult to override the default styles. In this case, you have two options-

Use an id-

Give the element you want to style any id. It has the highest specificity.

```
#mynav{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Use `!important`-

Although not very much recommended, but using `!important` even overrides id. In your case -

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Yegor Androsov has mentioned, there is no `.navbar-default`. Therefore, the text color you are trying to apply won't work as you have it:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Consider:

```css
.navbar .navbar-brand{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

This will work for the code as it is in the screenshot. However, if you change and include `.navbar-default`, remember to adjust your specificity appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elements with `navbar-default` class, so I think that's the reason for the rule is not working.

This should be better:

```
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

It's applied to all elements matching `.navbar-brand` selector (which means elements with `class` attribute containing `navbar-brand`) inside all elements matching `.navbar` selector (elements with `class` containing `navbar`).

You can test it very fast in your browser's console with `document.querySelectorAll()` method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-default');
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .navbar-brand');
```

Each command will return an array of elements that match your CSS selector you can expand and have elements highlighted on the page when you put your mouse over them.